# Pass request rest-api data to flask html

Tags: python, html, rest, api, flask

I just started play-around with flask and html.

I have a python file that make a request to a url and return the output in  json. The output is printed on the terminal. Now, I want to get the output to be shown in html page. I have gone with few tutorial..but difficult to understand and to adopt it based on my own data.

Python file without any flask/html

```
def topo():
    response = requests.get(network_url, auth = (user, pass))
    print(response)
    for nodes in response.json()['network-topology']['topology']:
        node_info = nodes['node']
        for node in node_info:
            try:
                ip_address = node['host-tracker-service:addresses'][0]['ip']
                mac_address = node['host-tracker-service:addresses'][0]['mac']
                print 'MAC address %s IP address %s' % (mac_address, ip_address)
            except:
                pass
```

and the code above return Terminal output as below

```
MAC address 00:00:00:00:00:01 IP address 10.0.0.1
MAC address 00:00:00:00:00:02 IP address 10.0.0.2
```

Below is the response from the rest-api request

```
{u'network-topology': {u'topology': [{u'node': [{u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1']", u'node-id': u'openflow:1', u'termination-point': [{u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1:2']", u'tp-id': u'openflow:1:2'}, {u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1:1']", u'tp-id': u'openflow:1:1'}, {u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:1:LOCAL']", u'tp-id': u'openflow:1:LOCAL'}]}, {u'host-tracker-service:addresses': [{u'first-seen': 1568245219561, u'ip': u'10.0.0.1', u'mac': u'00:00:00:00:00:01', u'id': 26, u'last-seen': 1568245219561}], u'host-tracker-service:id': u'00:00:00:00:00:01', u'host-tracker-service:attachment-points': [{u'active': True, u'corresponding-tp': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01', u'tp-id': u'openflow:1:1'}], u'node-id': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01', u'termination-point': [{u'tp-id': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01'}]}, {u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2']", u'node-id': u'openflow:2', u'termination-point': [{u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2:LOCAL']", u'tp-id': u'openflow:2:LOCAL'}, {u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2:1']", u'tp-id': u'openflow:2:1'}, {u'opendaylight-topology-inventory:inventory-node-connector-ref': u"/opendaylight-inventory:nodes/opendaylight-inventory:node[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2']/opendaylight-inventory:node-connector[opendaylight-inventory:id='openflow:2:2']", u'tp-id': u'openflow:2:2'}]}, {u'host-tracker-service:addresses': [{u'first-seen': 1568245219558, u'ip': u'10.0.0.2', u'mac': u'00:00:00:00:00:02', u'id': 25, u'last-seen': 1568245219558}], u'host-tracker-service:id': u'00:00:00:00:00:02', u'host-tracker-service:attachment-points': [{u'active': True, u'corresponding-tp': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02', u'tp-id': u'openflow:2:1'}], u'node-id': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02', u'termination-point': [{u'tp-id': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02'}]}], u'link': [{u'link-id': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01/openflow:1:1', u'destination': {u'dest-node': u'openflow:1', u'dest-tp': u'openflow:1:1'}, u'source': {u'source-tp': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01', u'source-node': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01'}}, {u'link-id': u'openflow:2:1/host:00:00:00:00:00:02', u'destination': {u'dest-node': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02', u'dest-tp': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02'}, u'source': {u'source-tp': u'openflow:2:1', u'source-node': u'openflow:2'}}, {u'link-id': u'openflow:1:2', u'destination': {u'dest-node': u'openflow:2', u'dest-tp': u'openflow:2:2'}, u'source': {u'source-tp': u'openflow:1:2', u'source-node': u'openflow:1'}}, {u'link-id': u'openflow:2:2', u'destination': {u'dest-node': u'openflow:1', u'dest-tp': u'openflow:1:2'}, u'source': {u'source-tp': u'openflow:2:2', u'source-node': u'openflow:2'}}, {u'link-id': u'openflow:1:1/host:00:00:00:00:00:01', u'destination': {u'dest-node': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01', u'dest-tp': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:01'}, u'source': {u'source-tp': u'openflow:1:1', u'source-node': u'openflow:1'}}, {u'link-id': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02/openflow:2:1', u'destination': {u'dest-node': u'openflow:2', u'dest-tp': u'openflow:2:1'}, u'source': {u'source-tp': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02', u'source-node': u'host:00:00:00:00:00:02'}}], u'topology-id': u'flow:1'}]}}
```

This is when I add route with flask and html page. Maybe I'm wrong here. Pls assist here.

```
@app.route('/')
def mypage():
   def topo():
    response = requests.get(network_url, auth = (user, pass))
    print(response)
    for nodes in response.json()['network-topology']['topology']:
          <snippet>


        return render_template('myweb.html', topo=json.loads(response.text)['network-topology'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

In the html template, i don't know exactly how to do it...how to link html page to my python file. Pls assist here...

```
<!-- myweb.html -->

<html>
<body>
  <h1>Topology</h1>
  {% ??????????? %}
    <div>{{?????["????????"]}}</div>
  {% ???? %}
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to see the HTML output in simple table like below

```
   MAC Address       IP Address
1. 00:00:00:00:00:01 10.0.0.1
2. 00:00:00:00:00:02 10.0.0.2
```

I  want to have the output onto html page. Just not clear how to do it with my own json data. Please show me the correct way of doing it. Thank you for your support and help.

Comment: you've cut your code so much that it's impossible to know exactly where the problem is. Is it on the python side or the HTML side? what result do you currently get on the python side? what exactly would you like to display on your page? give more details please.

Comment: You put a loop, but you never see what happens in the loop. What treatment do you do there? what result must he produce?

Comment: Hi Tobin, thanks for your response. I have updated the details. Pls advise further. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible approach:

**PYTHON'S SIDE**:

```
@app.route('/')
def mypage():
    def topo():
        response = requests.get(network_url, auth = (user, pass))
        print(response)
        list_of_mac_ip_address = []

        for nodes in response.json()['network-topology']['topology']:
            node_info = nodes['node']
            for node in node_info:
                dico = dict()
                try:
                    ip_address = node['host-tracker-service:addresses'][0]['ip']
                    mac_address = node['host-tracker-service:addresses'][0]['mac']
                    print 'MAC address %s IP address %s' % (mac_address, ip_address)

                    dico['IP'] = ip_address
                    dico['MAC'] = mac_address
                    list_of_mac_ip_address.append(dico)

                except:
                    pass

        return list_of_mac_ip_address

    list_of_mac_ip_address = topo()

    return render_template('myweb.html', list_ip_mac=list_of_mac_ip_address)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

**myweb.html**:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Topology</h1>
    <table id="yourTableID" width="100%" cellspacing="5">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> MAC Address </th>
                <th> IP Address </th>   
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for i in list_ip_mac %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{ i["IP"] }}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{ i["MAC"] }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>                 
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I create a list of dictionaries that I send on the HTML side. And with jinja I iterate through this list to retrieve the different IP and MAC addresses.

Comment: Hi...sir...the html page able to browse...but it just have heading (h1) and header information (th)...no data of mac address and ip address show on the page. From the python file it does show --> MAC address 00:00:00:00:00:01 IP address 10.0.0.1
MAC address 00:00:00:00:00:02 IP address 10.0.0.2
10.44.45.10 - - [03/Oct/2019 05:46:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -  just the data is not populate onto the html page

Comment: Go to line `list_of_mac_ip_address = topo( )`. try to print it. what do you get? then check the names of your variables...

Comment: it return zero list like this ---> []  which variable to check?

Comment: Anyway... is there any other method...other than create list here and iterate it on the html page...do we must simplified it onto clean list (already extract the specific key) and html only iterate the list ...thanks

Comment: Try to add prints at each level, especially in the try statement. Check what's in the dico, in the list and make sure that the topo function returns something.

Comment: You should get a list of dictionaries. On the html side the logic is good, it should work.

Comment: Hi...sir thank you. now able to see the data on the html page... create new file and run ...ok...

Comment: in this code only have singe for loop and it return list_of_mac_ip_address.... may i know if got one than more for loop for example 1st loop return list_of_mac_ip_address and i add another for loop to return list of devices .... can i have 2 return in single function and how to combine it so that both can be send to html page... i may open new for this question...but just to get some ideas...thank you sir.